# Array seems to lose values after end of for loop

Tags: go

I'm a beginner at go (and not a good programmer) but I wanted to write a small program which would dump from a switch the list of mac addresses & interfaces name using snmp. I store the snmp values into an array of struct using multiple loops (the code here is to show the behavior).
During the first loop, I store Ports Vlan id & mac addresses into an array of struct (var allTableArray [30]allTable). At the end of this loop, I print the content of the array to be sure the mac addresses are in the array.
But when the second loop begins (to register bridge port number), the array seems empty (`fmt.Printf("deux %x\n",allTableArray[i].macAddr) and     fmt.Printf("trois %s\n",allTableArray[i].ptVlan1id))`.

I don't understand why my array seems empty. Do you have any idea ?

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"
    "strings"
    "github.com/soniah/gosnmp"
    "math/big"
)

type oidMacAddr struct {
    oid string
    macaddr string
}

type allTable struct {
    ptVlan1id string
    macAddr []byte
    brPortNb *big.Int
    ifIndex *big.Int
    ifName string
}

var macAddrTable [30]oidMacAddr


func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    if len(flag.Args()) < 1 {
            flag.Usage()
            os.Exit(1)
    }
    target := flag.Args()[0]
    showMacAddrTable(target)
}

func printValue(pdu gosnmp.SnmpPDU) error {
    fmt.Printf("%s = ", pdu.Name)

    //fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(pdu.Value.([]byte)))
    switch pdu.Type {
    case gosnmp.OctetString:
            b := pdu.Value.([]byte)
            fmt.Printf("STRING: %x\n", b)
    default:
            fmt.Printf("TYPE %d: %d\n", pdu.Type, gosnmp.ToBigInt(pdu.Value))
    }
    return nil
}


func showMacAddrTable(target string) () {

    var allTableArray [30]allTable
    ptVlan1Oid := ".1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1"
    brPortOid := ".1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.2"
    brPortIfIndex := ".1.3.6.1.2.1.17.1.4.1.2"
    ifIndexIfName := ".1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1"
    community := "public"

    gosnmp.Default.Target = target
    gosnmp.Default.Community = community
    gosnmp.Default.Timeout = time.Duration(10 * time.Second) // Timeout better suited to walking
    err := gosnmp.Default.Connect()
    if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Connect err: %v\n", err)
            os.Exit(1)
    }

    var essai []gosnmp.SnmpPDU
    essai, err = gosnmp.Default.BulkWalkAll(ptVlan1Oid)
    if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Walk Error: %v\n", err)
            os.Exit(1)
    }
    for i :=0 ; i < len(essai); i++ {
            s := strings.TrimPrefix(essai[i].Name, ".1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1")
            fmt.Printf("%s = ", s)
            fmt.Printf("%x\n", essai[i].Value.([]byte))
            bytes := essai[i].Value.([]byte)
            macAddrTable[i] = oidMacAddr {s, string(bytes)}
            allTableArray[i] = allTable {ptVlan1id: s, macAddr: bytes}
            if(allTableArray[i].macAddr != nil){
                    fmt.Printf("%x\n",allTableArray[i].macAddr)
            }


    }
    essai, err = gosnmp.Default.BulkWalkAll(brPortOid)
    if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Walk Error: %v\n", err)
            os.Exit(1)
    }
    for i:=0 ; i < len(essai); i++ {
            s := strings.TrimPrefix(essai[i].Name, ".1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.2")
            fmt.Printf("%s = ", s)
            fmt.Printf("%d\n", essai[i].Value)
            for j:=0 ; j < len(allTableArray); j++ {
                    if (s == allTableArray[j].ptVlan1id) {
                            allTableArray[j] = allTable {brPortNb: gosnmp.ToBigInt(essai[i].Value) }
                    }
            }
                    fmt.Printf("deux %x\n",allTableArray[i].macAddr)
                    fmt.Printf("trois %s\n",allTableArray[i].ptVlan1id)
    }

    os.Exit(1)
}
```

Comment: Is the array empty when you print it out before the first loop ends at `fmt.Printf(%x\n, allTableArray[i].macAddr`?

Comment: No, the array doesn't seem empty because the Printf prints out the mac addresses:
It displays data like this before the end of the first loop:
.12.196.122.5.50.246 = 0xx47a053xxx
0xx47a053xxx
.0.37.144.88.177.153 = 23

Comment: It is likely because you filled the `allTableArray` with `nil` at this point. `allTableArray[j] = allTable {brPortNb: gosnmp.ToBigInt(essai[i].Value)`. Try switching to some other value to test if that's the case.

Comment: .0.37.144.204.23.61 = 1
deux
trois
quatre 25
.12.196.122.5.50.246 = 14
deux
trois
quatre 26

Only the variable that is accessed during the loop seems to be displayed (here quatre displays the content of j variable) and not the ones that are inserted in the loop before (macaddr & ptVlan1Id).

Comment: Ok, allTable {brPortNb: gosnmp.ToBigInt(essai[i].Value) is not the correct way to insert data into an array which already contains data as it sets nil to all other fields. I need to find the right way to do this in golang documentation.

Comment: I found this workaround to keep the previous data:
 `allTableArray[j] = allTable {ptVlan1id: allTableArray[j].ptVlan1id, macAddr: allTableArray[j].macAddr, brPortNb: big.NewInt(int64(j))}`

Is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this line

```
allTableArray[j] = allTable {brPortNb: gosnmp.ToBigInt(essai[i].Value) }
```

Update each member with a new `allTable` instance, where every field other than `brPortNb` is not defined thus becomes `nil`.

If what you were trying to do is to update each member's `brPortNb` field, you could have done so by accessing the field and assign the value to it **instead of assigning a new `allTable` to every member**.

```
allTableArray[j].brPortNb = gosnmp.ToBigInt(essai[i].Value)
```

Also, try simplifying your loops like this, provided `len(essai) == len(allTableArray)`:

```
for i, v := range essai {
        s := strings.TrimPrefix(v.Name, ".1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1")
        bytes := v.Value.([]byte)
        macAddrTable[i] = oidMacAddr { s, string(bytes) }
        allTableArray[i] = allTable { ptVlan1id: s, macAddr: bytes }

        s = strings.TrimPrefix(v.Name, ".1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.2")
        if s == allTableArray[i].ptVlan1id {
                allTableArray[i].brPortNb = gosnmp.ToBigInt(v.Value)
        }
}
```

Notice that by using `for i, v := range essai` syntax, you have access to both the index and the value without having to use `essai[i]` for the value.

Now your two loops can become just one, plus no embedded loops which are really hard to make sense of.

I Also recommend you work with slice instead of array. It's more flexible that way.

Comment: `for i, v := range essai` will create a copy of `essai[i]` stored in `v`. Aside from lower performance because of the copy, you won't be able to modify it:
http://play.golang.org/p/MhVRf5qY4t